# Making a image switcher

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to make a very simple image switcher where basically when an item from a list is clicked the picture on a div changes.

I can't get it to work. Could you point me a solution about how to make this code below works?

```
<head>
   <style>
      li img { height: 30px; border: 1px dashed blue;}
      .main_image { border: 1px solid black; height: 500px; width: 500px; }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('li img').click( function() {
       $('#main').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
     });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="main_image">
      <img id="main" src="" /> 
   </div>

   <ul>
       <li>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="Image Name" />
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="Image Name" />
       </li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: So you have a gallery of thumbnails, and you want to update the "master" image when clicking a thumbnail?

Comment: That works - http://jsfiddle.net/y3m4w/ , just use css to force the size of the image

Comment: rickyduck... funny how my code worked on jsfiddle. Its not working on my localhost or neither on any of my servers online... :(

Answer (score 1):

The mark-up:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x450" alt="" class="main" />
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/600x450"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x75" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/600x450"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x75" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/600x450"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x75" alt="" /></a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('.gallery').each(function () {
    var gallery = this;
    $('.thumbnails a', gallery).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('img.main', gallery).attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

This should work for any main image/thumbnail combination wrapped in a `<div>` with a class of `gallery` as in the above mark-up.

So for example, you could have multiple galleries on the same page, and the above jQuery snippet will work independently for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```js
$("li img").click(
    function(){
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $("img#main").attr("src", imgSrc);
    }
);
```

Not tested but should work :)
Shai.