# Multiple Image Switchers in one page

Tags: php, javascript

How do I make multiple Image Switchers work on one page?

Here is what I tried and works fine for one image switcher.

Notes: I want to use the same image for thumbnail and main image. Please follow my idea. :)

```
<head>
   <style>
      li img { height: 30px; border: 1px dashed blue;}
      .main_image { border: 1px solid black; height: 500px; width: 500px; }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('li img').click( function() {
       $('.main').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
     });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="image-switcher-001">
   <div class="main_image">
      <img class="main" src="" /> 
   </div>

   <ul>
       <li>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="Image Name" />
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="Image Name" />
       </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="image-switcher-002">
   <div class="main_image">
      <img class="main" src="" /> 
   </div>

   <ul>
       <li>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="Image Name" />
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="Image Name" />
       </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a image switcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139754/making-a-image-switcher)

Comment: Not really... that question was an issue that I had yesterday. Today I'm still stuck with this thing trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that the `$('.main')` part selects *all* `.main` elements.

instead of `$('.main')`, try `$(this).closest('div').find('.main')` .

that goes up the DOM tree to the nearest `<div/>`, then down to the `.main` inside it.